# Как отфильтровать массив, чтобы выводилась одна url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Данным кодом получаю список фотографий в количестве 20-ти штук с определенной группы в ВК, с помощью их API:

```
async function fetchPhotoGroup() {
            const getToken = await bridge.send('VKWebAppGetAuthToken', {
                app_id: 51510243,
                scope: 'photos'
            });
            const photoGroup = await bridge.send('VKWebAppCallAPIMethod', {
                method: 'photos.getAll',
                params: {
                    owner_id: '-187730433',
                    count: '20',
                    v: '5.131',
                    access_token: getToken.access_token
            }});
    setPopout(null);
    setPhotoGroup(photoGroup.response.items);
}
fetchPhotoGroup();
```

В ответ получаю 20 подобных объектов:

```
{
album_id: 273229142,
date: 1668793160,
has_tags: false,
id: 457262399,
owner_id: -187730433,
sizes: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
text: "",
user_id: 100,
}
```

Внутри этого объекта есть массив "sizes" с 10 разными форматами изображения[image: введите сюда описание изображения] :

Мне нужно из каждого объекта при получении брать одну выбранную url из "sizes" и выводить их.

Comment: Удалите картинку и добавьте данные текстом, а так же ваши попытки сделать фильтрацию объекта и что не получилось?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.